# Backgrounding behaviour when an outgoing phone call is made, iOS7 vs iOS8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8

When my iOS app makes a phone call by doing the following:

```
NSString *telephoneUrl = @"tel:12345678";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:telephoneUrl]];
```

what happens to the app lifecycle state?

e.g. if I put the following lines below the above phone call lines:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"dispatch callback was called!!!");
});
```

On iOS 7, `applicationDidEnterBackground` is called, the above code doesn't run, and when the phone call terminates, I am inside the Phone app. The console lines are written only when i return to my app.

However, on iOS 8, only `applicationWillResignActive` is called and the app doesn't enter background, and you can actually see the log being written to the console while I am inside the phone call. When the call terminates, i am still inside my app.

Can someone confirm the behaviour, or point me to the relevant documentation?

Comment: It sounds like iOS 8 does not actually background the app but simply places the phone app on top of yours. This same functionality can be experienced by loading Siri up. The app isn't the active app, but it's not been backgrounded either.

Do you have an actual problem you're seeking help with or are you just looking for more information about states?

Also, you might just be doing this for debugging reasons, but setting code to execute after so much time should be avoided (obviously, there are plenty of situations where that is the only thing that makes sense but speaking generally here).

Comment: I was hoping someone might have the definitive documentation about the phone call behaviour, rather than my own trial and error. Thanks for the info about the Siri scenario, it's a useful example.

Comment: I would normally do a better job about providing links and more full fledged comments, but I'm restricted to cell phone use atm, so anything I'm typing, I'm doing from memory. Although it should be noted a lot of the iOS 8 docs are currently more of a description of intended behavior vs actual - still a lot of bugs they're working through.

Answer (score 0):

Yes iOS 7 & iOS 8 are different here. And I can't find document about it either.

So in iOS 7 if you have an incoming call applicationWillResignActive: will be called first. If you reject the phone applicationDidEnterBackground will not be called;but if you answer the phone applicationDidEnterBackground will be called and when you end the phone and your app become active again applicationWillEnterForeground: will be called too.

But in iOS 8 only applicationWillResignActive: will be called no matter you answer the phone or not.